# Alternative way to using mem_fun1() have been removed in Visual C++ 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Function `mem_fun1()` have been removed in VC++ 2015. Therefore I change my code to using `mem_fun1_t()` from:

```
mem_fun1(&classA::functA)
```

To:

```
mem_fun1_t<bool,classA,classB>(&classA::functA)
```

With declare of function `functA()`:

```
bool classA::functA(classB x);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: `mem_fun1_t` has also been removed since C++17. Looking at a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) for `mem_fun` might tell you why it was removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old member function adaptors are strictly superseded by [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn). Use that, not deprecated functions that are removed in C++17 (and will likely be removed from later versions of VS).

As to `mem_fun1`, that's never been in the standard. The standard had four `mem_fun` overloads to handle const and non-const member function pointers with either 0 or 1 arguments.